# Merging Private Sub functions in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written three different **Private Sub** functions, all of which do the same thing **Private Sub txt_noRooms_KeyPress** and **Private Sub txt_length_KeyPress** ensure that the user can only type in values 1 to 9 into the referenced text fields whereas **Private Sub txt_studentNo_KeyPress** allows the user to type in values 0 to 9 into the referenced text field.

Is there any way I can merge these three functions and have them still support the referenced cells and maintain the same conditions? I want to do this for the purpose of making the code more efficient.

```
Private Sub txt_noRooms_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
' Restrict entry to txt_noRooms
Select Case KeyAscii
    Case Asc("1") To Asc("9")
    Case Asc("-")
        If InStr(1, Me.txt_noRooms.Text, "-") > 0 Or Me.txt_noRooms.SelStart > 0 Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        End If
    Case Asc(".")
        If InStr(1, Me.txt_noRooms.Text, ".") > 0 Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        End If
    Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
End Select
End Sub


Private Sub txt_length_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)   
' Restrict entry to txt_length
Select Case KeyAscii
    Case Asc("1") To Asc("9")
    Case Asc("-")
        If InStr(1, Me.txt_length.Text, "-") > 0 Or Me.txt_length.SelStart > 0 Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        End If
    Case Asc(".")
        If InStr(1, Me.txt_length.Text, ".") > 0 Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        End If
    Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
End Select
End Sub


Private Sub txt_studentNo_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
' Restrict entry to txt_studentNo
Select Case KeyAscii
    Case Asc("0") To Asc("9")
    Case Asc("-")
        If InStr(1, Me.txt_studentNo.Text, "-") > 0 Or Me.txt_studentNo.SelStart > 0 Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        End If
    Case Asc(".")
        If InStr(1, Me.txt_studentNo.Text, ".") > 0 Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        End If
    Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set one private function and call it from each keypress:

```
  Private Sub txt_noRooms_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
' Restrict entry to txt_noRooms
If bclearfield(CLng(KeyAscii), Me.txt_noRooms.Text, Me.txt_noRooms.selStart,"1")  Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub


Private Sub txt_length_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
' Restrict entry to txt_length
If bclearfield(CLng(KeyAscii), Me.txt_length.Text, Me.txt_length.selStart,"1") Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub

Private Sub txt_studentNo_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
' Restrict entry to txt_studentNo
If bclearfield(CLng(KeyAscii), Me.txt_studentNo.Text, Me.txt_studentNo.selStart,"0") Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub

Private Function bClearField(KeyAscii As Long, sText As String, lSelStart As Long,sLowLimit as string) As boolean

bClearField=false
Select Case KeyAscii
    Case Asc(sLowLimit ) To Asc("9")
    Case Asc("-")
        If InStr(1, sText, "-") > 0 Or lSelStart > 0 Then
            bClearField=true
        End If
    Case Asc(".")
        If InStr(1, sText, ".") > 0 Then
            bClearField=true
        End If
    Case Else
        bClearField=true
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: I can't seem to type anything into the fields now

Comment: have you tried setting a breakpoint (`F9`) in one of the keypress subs and step into the code  (`F8`) to see what the issue is?

Comment: I've changed the var type for the function return. Don't know if that would help.

Comment: I'm getting a Run Time Error 91 whenever I try to type in something into the field

Comment: `Case Else
        GetKeyAscii = 0
End Select`

Comment: I think I got it, no matter what the input was, my function would return 0, since no output would turn into a 0 long value. Try the updated code.

Comment: The error message is gone but the text field is still not accepting input :-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17899/discussion-between-nutsch-and-methuselah)